# Morphism between affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Humphrey’s Linear algebraic groups. In chapter 2, he said general linear group $GL_n$ is an affine variety since it is principal open subsets of $\mathbb A^{n^2}$. To show $GL_n$ is an affine variety in $\mathbb {A}^{n^2}$, we let $V$ be an affine variety in $\mathbb {A}^{n^2+1}$ defined by $det(a_{ij})t-1=0$. Then we show $GL_n$ isomorphic to $V$. Isomorphism is given by sending $(a_{ij})$ to $(a_{ij},\frac{1}{det(a_{ij})})$. However, morphism between affine varieties is polynomial map, and $\frac{1}{det(a_{ij})}$ is not a polynomial. I am confusing about this part. How to understand this isomorphism?

Here I take definition of morphism of affine varieties as: a map $f: X \to Y$ between $X\subset \mathbb A^n, Y\subset \mathbb A^m$ is a morphism if $f(x)=(g_1(x),…,g_m(x))$ where $g_i\in K[X]$

Comment: Typically, one takes as their morphisms *regular maps*, which are locally quotients of polynomials. Your question would be improved by some information about your background: what text or course you're studying out of, the definitions they use, etc. Please consider making an [edit] to include some of this information.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for advices. I’ve edited a bit.